# What is (the current prefered definition) of a cleavage of a TCP = twisted cartesan Product?

Tags: products, fiber-bundles, simplicial-stuff

Cleavage of a TCP refers to unique lifting of fillers of simplicial $k$-horns in an $n$-simplex in the base of a TCP. Two definitions appear to disagree: $k < n$ versus $k \leq n$